# How can I create a txt file with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I create a txt file in a folder with Inno Setup?

```
[Run]
SaveStringToFile('c:\filename.txt', #13#10 + 'the string' + #13#10, True);
```

The code doesn't work, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the code (`SaveStringToFile`) from an event function or possibly from a UI-control handler. You didn't specify when you want the file to be created. Assuming you want to create it as part of the installation, you can use [`CurStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) in `ssInstall` (pre-install) or `ssPostInstall` steps.

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if Step = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    SaveStringToFile('c:\filename.txt', #13#10 + 'the string' + #13#10, True);
  end;
end;
```

*Though hard-coding `C:` drive seems like a bad idea.*